# Jest is not recognized by typescript

Tags: jestjs, ts-jest

--- UPDATE----
I can run the test using command line but can't run the test with Jest Runner extension in VSCode.

------Original Question -----------------

I think I have corrupted my npm modules because I tried to install some more recent version of jest and ts-jest related modules in my project (was hoping to fix some test related problem) but it caused a lot of other problems so I just reverted the `package.json` and `package.lock.json`.

Now in my test files, it doesn't recognize `jest` anymore. Typescript simple shows a bunch of errors complaining it can't find `jest`, can't find `describe` (which is defined in jest).

I tried to delete the node_modules folder and run `npm install`, that didn't help. I cleared npm cache; it didn't help.
Not sure what else I can try.

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist",

    "allowJs": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,

    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jest"
    ],
    "baseUrl":".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
      "src/*"
      ]
      },
  },

  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "*.ts",
    "src/**/*.json"
    ]
}
```

Sorry but not sure what else I can share apart from a screenshot in this particular case.

[image]

---- Add part of package.json ----
[image]

Comment: add `jest` as a type in your tsconfig.json.

Comment: it's already there; just updated the question @hoangdv

Comment: Seems like you are missing @types/jest package.  You could remove your `node_modules` and then `npm install` to recreate if you think it’s corruption.

Comment: I did try that as said in the question but somehow it didn't help. @DaveMeehan

Comment: @DaveMeehan how come I don't see a `types/jest` folder in my `node_modules?

Comment: It should be a dependency. Can you show relevant part of your package.json?  Note that the leading `@` is important.

Comment: @DaveMeehan. I just added part of the package.json to the question.

Comment: @types/jest is one major version behind the current, jest is two majors behind.  You might want to try uninstalling all of the jest related deps and reinstalling them (or use `npm upgrade` with appropriate options).  Did you follow the steps outlined in the other answer?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case this helps someone in the future. The issue is resolved by adding `"**/*.spec.ts"` to the `include` in the `tsconfig.json`

Not sure why this is needed as it was working fine before; guess it must be because some partial upgrade I did.

Comment: do you have to run npm install again or .tsc or anything?

Answer (score 4):

What I always do when I have to test my projects is the following. I will try to explain step by step.

1- Remove everything related to Karma/Jasmine in the **package.json**:

```
npm remove <karma karma-chrome-launcher...>
```

Inside the <> type everything related to those libraries.

2- Install Jest:

```
npm install --save-dev jest jest-preset-angular @types/jest
```

3- Create **setup-jest.ts** in the root folder of your project, and put this inside:

```
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest';
```

4- Add jest config to **package.json**:

```
"jest": {
    "preset": "jest-preset-angular",
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts"
    ],
    "globalSetup": "jest-preset-angular/global-setup"
  }
```

5- Configure JEST in **tsconfig.json** and tsconfig.spec.json, add this:

```
"types": [
  "jest"
]
```

6- Configure commands to test your app:

```
"test": "jest",
"test:watch": "jest --watchAll",
```

7- Remove **karma.config.json** and **test.ts**.

This should work if you are using Angular. I don't work with other framework/library, so I don't really know if this is how you do it there.

Comment: Sorry but this is from Vue not Angular. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This documentation is better than the official documentation itself! Thank you @AhmedSHA256

Comment: “5- Configure JEST in tsconfig.json and tsconfig.spec.json, add this“. is adding "types": [
  "jest"
] in both files are required? Or only in tsconfig.spec.json?

Comment: I can't give you a proper answer im afraid, so try both adding and not adding and see if something breaks. Comment what happens please so I can update my answer according to that, please